# Capistrano floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot (SyntaxError)

Tags: capistrano

I have a little bit of experience using Capistrano but only on projects that are already using it and I am currently trying to set it up on a new project. I have created my config/deploy.rb file, added the appropriate configuration and am now trying to run "cap deploy:setup" to set the correct capistrano structure up on my remote server however now when I try to run this or any other Capistrano commands I get:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval': ./config/deploy.rb:8: no . floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot (SyntaxError)
role :web, xxx.x.xx.xx
```

It looks like an issue with the format of the IP that I have provided for my app but no variations seem to work.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

I found a resolution for this in the end through trial and error. It turns out that I needed to wrap the role :web and role :app values in quotes:

"xx.xx.xx.xx"

Then it worked correctly.